# Почему текст сохраняется после postback?

Tags: asp.net

Почему если у textbox отключить EnableViewState, текст после postback всё-равно сохраняется?

Answer (score 2):

Отключение EnableViewState здесь ничего не даст, так как текст в textbox-ах сохраняется браузером. Чтобы избежать сохранения нужно:

1. Установить у textbox-a `autocomplete="off"` (или у формы)
2. Указать текст по умолчанию.

Пример:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

или:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox1" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

При PostBack на сервер отправляется форма в виде ID_контрола=значение. Значение каждого контрола присутствует в форме. View State тоже присутствует в форме, но отключение View State не помешает передаче значения, ввёденного в `TextBox`.

TextBox реализует интерфейс [IPostBackDataHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) . Если посмотреть Reflector'ом на метод [LoadPostData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.loadpostdata.aspx), то увидим, что `TextBox` берёт значение `Text` из данных Post'a

```
protected virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
{
    base.ValidateEvent(postDataKey);
    string text = this.Text;
    string str2 = postCollection[postDataKey];
    if (!this.ReadOnly && !text.Equals(str2, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        this.Text = str2;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Таким образом, свойство `Text` берётся не из View State, а всегда равно тому, что ввёл пользователь.